# How do you use "codify" when you 're talking about coding?

Tags: verbs

In this document, I found "codify"

https://www.terraform.io/intro/use-cases.html

1.

> Terraform can be used to codify the setup required for a Heroku application

2.

> Because the creation and provisioning of a resource is codified and automated

How do you use "codify" when you 're talking about coding?

Comment: For us to answer properly, we need a better understanding of what you’re trying to express. Can you supply a few examples and then explain what they are intended to say? For example, the first sentence in your block quote seems to say that you can use the program Terraform as a tool (text editor?) to write the step-by-step instructions for the ‘setup’ mentioned. But maybe the intent was instead that Terraform can be used as a programming language to write the setup as a piece of code. Unfortunately, that interpretation isn’t the natural reading of the sentence.

Comment: In over 40 years of programming, I have never heard someone use "codify" to refer to the act of programming, except perhaps sarcastically.

Comment: Did you notice, neither "Terraform can be used to codify the setup required for a Heroku application" nor "Because the creation and provisioning of a resource is codified and automated" has any real meaning in English?

If you;'re looking for a serious answer, why not first put your examples into full English sentances?

Comment: Sorry, two sentence is independent. I inserted the line but the editer display it as if it is one quotation

Comment: I think the idea is that once the setup requirements are written down, everyone can do it the same way and it won't change.  Just like values are codified when laws are written down and all judges enforce them the same way, the setup parameters are codified when entered in the automation system and every system gets set up the same way.

Comment: What do you mean by "coding"? This question is far too vague.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse "codify" with "code-ify".  "Codify" means to simplify, summarize or make sense of a bunch of facts.  It would be better to use the words "encode" or "program" if the most likely meaning of the neologism "CODE-ify" was intended.

In this case, it sounds like the intended meaning of "codify" and "codified" is "simplify" and "simplified", as the setup for Heroku apps is probably complicated yet used over & over, thus the need for automation.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen a lot of code that's iffy.

Comment: @HotLicks :D That's phunny!

Comment: Software engineers often talk about codifying requirements, interfaces, protocols, maybe designs, and other features that are needed to implement code, but I agree that codifying code doesn't make sense.